# How to handle a CSS property of clicked object in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Tell me please, how to handle onclick action by ID. For example, i’ve something in hbs template:

```
<button id="myButton" {{action "myAction"}} >OK</button>
```

it has CSS:

```
button {color: "red";}
```

How to do two things by onclick action:

```
1. Set property to clicked object (only to clicked), eg to set CSS colour “green”,
2. Get some property of clicked (eg CSS colour), and console log or alert.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the action to the "onclick" event of the button like this

```
<button id="myButton" onclick={{action "myAction"}} >OK</button>
```

And then the first argument of the action will be the click event, from which you can take the target DOM element.

Check out this example twiddle:
https://ember-twiddle.com/1d14560e0e979dbbdddbfee57c84601c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C